# Rolling averages in SQL for assets which are added progressively to the population

Tags: sql, postgresql, apache-spark-sql, moving-average, rolling-average

My data-table has various assets along with the groups they belong to and the date of entry into that group/population/data-table.

Now I can calculate the average age of the assets but how would I actually go about calculating an average age over a period of time so for example for Group A, I can calculate it for Assets SN 001 and SN 004 but how do I go about getting a running average since Date of Entry and in a Year-on-Year format.

I apologise if I am unclear, I would be happy to elaborate.

| Asset | Group | Date of Entry |
| --- | --- | --- |
| SN 001 | A | 2011-01-01 |
| SN 002 | B | 2014-06-01 |
| SN 003 | C | 2015-01-01 |
| SN 004 | A | 2018-06-01 |
| SN 005 | B | 2019-01-01 |
| SN 006 | C | 2021-06-01 |

Desired Result: Where # is the average age and changes based on the addition of Assets to each group and adjusts accordingly.

| Date of Entry (Y) | AVG_Group A | AVG_Group B | AVG_Group C |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2011 | # | # | # |
| 2012 | # | # | # |
| 2013 | # | # | # |
| 2014 | # | # | # |
| 2015 | # | # | # |
| 2016 | # | # | # |
| 2017 | # | # | # |
| 2018 | # | # | # |
| 2019 | # | # | # |
| 2020 | # | # | # |
| 2021 | # | # | # |

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this :

```
SELECT extract(year from y.year)
     , avg(age(y.year, "Date of Entry")) FILTER (WHERE "Group" = 'A' AND "Date of Entry" <= y.year) AS "AVG_Group A"
     , avg(age(y.year, "Date of Entry")) FILTER (WHERE "Group" = 'B' AND "Date of Entry" <= y.year) AS "AVG_Group B"
     , avg(age(y.year, "Date of Entry")) FILTER (WHERE "Group" = 'C' AND "Date of Entry" <= y.year) AS "AVG_Group C"
  FROM (SELECT generate_series(min(date_trunc('year', "Date of Entry")), max(date_trunc('year', "Date of Entry")), interval '1 year') AS year
          FROM your_table
       ) AS y
 CROSS JOIN your_table AS t
 GROUP BY y.year
 ORDER BY y.year
```

see the test result in [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=91bd664aac61c30adf23ef21b96b4f4c).